# How to Delete Row in CSV if adjacent rows have duplicate values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science, openpyxl

I am trying to delete the adjacent rows with same values but it gives me memory error, how I can do it?

Before program

```
      col1       col2     col3     col4       col5
row1             5
row2             5
row3             6
row4             5
```

After program

```
      col1       col2     col3     col4       col5
row1             5
row2             6
row3             5
```

Kindly help , While I wrote a function which gives me memory error;

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook


wb = load_workbook(filename="sample.xlsx")
sheet = wb.active
for i in range(2,526023):
    j = i+1
    if (sheet["F"+str(i)].value==sheet["F"+str(j)].value):
        sheet.delete_rows(j)
wb.save("sample.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx')

df = df[df['col2'] != df['col2'].shift()]

df.to_excel('sample.xlsx')
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation as to why this is a suitable answer? Code is much more helpful for future readers if it is expanded upon.